# How to verify a date is a weekend in Visual Basic

Tags: arrays, date, basic

I have an array that is storing dates from a date time picker and I need to verify if any of the dates are on weekends (Saturdays and Sundays) to charge a surcharge on top of the BaseRate. The dates array is used to fill the array with the dates in between the startDate and endDate. This code doesn't seem to work the way I thought:

```
Dim dates(Nights) as Date
For i As Integer = 0 To Nights
        dates(i) = StartDay
        StartDay.AddDays(1)
Next

For i As Integer = 0 To Nights
    If dates(i).Day = DayOfWeek.Saturday Or dates(i).Day = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
        BaseRate += (BaseRate * dclWeekendSurcharge)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Should `dates(i). = DayOfWeek.Saturday` be `dates(i).Day = DayOfWeek.Saturday`? Looks like you're missing Day on the Saturday

Comment: That was a typo on here on my part. It's fixed in the code and still doesn't run correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The `Day` property is day of month, not day of week. Use the `DayOfWeek` property of the Date object to compare against the DayOfWeek enum accurately.

```
Dim dates(Nights) as Date
For i As Integer = 0 To Nights
    If dates(i).DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday Or dates(i).DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
        BaseRate += (BaseRate * dclWeekendSurcharge)
    End If
Next
```

The concept could be converted to a rate calculation for a stay duration with the sample code below:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Dim nightlyRate as Decimal = 60 '$60/night
Dim weekendSurcharge as Decimal = 0.1 '10% higher
System.Console.WriteLine("$60 = ${0}", GetTotal(Date.Parse("1/1/2015"), Date.Parse("1/2/2015"), nightlyRate, weekendSurcharge))
System.Console.WriteLine("$120 = ${0}", GetTotal(Date.Parse("1/1/2015"), Date.Parse("1/3/2015"), nightlyRate, weekendSurcharge))
System.Console.WriteLine("$186 = ${0}", GetTotal(Date.Parse("1/1/2015"), Date.Parse("1/4/2015"), nightlyRate, weekendSurcharge))

Function GetTotal(startDay as Date, endDay as Date, baseRate as Decimal, weekendSurcharge as Decimal) as Decimal
    Dim total as Decimal = 0
        Do While startDay < endDay
            total += baseRate
            If startDay.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday Or startDay.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
                total += (baseRate * weekendSurcharge) 'Assume surchage is a multiplier, not a dollar rate
            End If
            startDay = startDay.AddDays(1)
        Loop
    Return total
End Function
```

This then outputs:

```
$60 = $60 '1 night, no weekend
$120 = $120 '2 nights, no weekend
$186 = $186.0 'This is with the 10% multiplier since 1/3 is a weekend
```

Comment: Would this be the proper way to fill the dates array?
    For i As Integer = 0 To Nights
        dates(i) = StartDay
        StartDay.AddDays(1)
    Next

Comment: If you are just trying to calculate the the total rate to charge having to account for the surcharge, there is a bit easier way than the array. Do you just need to total rate to charge for the stay?

Comment: What I need is to have the user pick a start date and end date for reservations and if any of the dates within that range fall on a weekend, they have a surcharge added to their total price.